# flask sqlalchemy query which returns sum from one table outer join to another with group by and a sub query with variables and case when

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am building an accounting database with flask front end. I have a main table called Book which is the main ledger, I need to query three columns to be able to see the amount of money spent/made. here is an example of the table

```sql
    debit  | credit |  montant
   -------------------------
    445663 | 1       | 56.23
    607002 | 1       | 178.36
    1      | 401000  | 244.59
```

here are the two tables:

```py
    class Book(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
        debit = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("general.id"))
        credit = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("general.id"))
        montant = db.Column(db.Float)
        Debit = db.relationship("General", foreign_keys=[debit])
        Credit = db.relationship("General", foreign_keys=[credit])

    class General(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

I have a raw query from Libre Office base that I want to use as a query in a flask view function but I am struggling to make the change. There are two sub queries inside which I have been able to translate into flask-sqlalchemy which works. Here are the sub queries:

```py
    mongendeb2plus = Book.query.with_entities(Book.montant).filter(Book.PID==pid, extract('month', Book.date)==month, Book.debit==gen).subquery()

    mongencred2plus = Book.query.with_entities(Book.montant).filter(Book.PID==pid, extract('month', Book.date)==month, Book.credit==gen).subquery()
```

I have been following [nested queries](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/nested-queries-with-sqlalchemy-orm) which uses nested queries. and I have watched this which talks about joins and group [group](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HIY1lZKEw0) but I am lost, here is the raw sql code:

```sql
    SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT "ID", "DEBIT", "CREDIT", 
    CASE WHEN "CREDIT" IS 1 THEN 0 ELSE "CREDIT" END - 
    CASE WHEN "DEBIT" IS 1 THEN 0 ELSE "DEBIT" END "Solde" 
    FROM "Genaral"
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT "Dedit", SUM( "mongendeb2plus"."montant" ) "DEBIT" FROM "mongendeb2plus" GROUP BY "Dedit" ) "A" ON "Genaral"."id" = "A"."Dedit" 
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT "Crebit", SUM( "mongencred2plus"."montant" ) "CREDIT" FROM "mongencred2plus" GROUP BY "Crebit" ) "B" ON "Genaral"."id" = "B"."Crebit" )
```

I have trawled through many question here on this site but unfortunatly my knowledge of sql and sqlalchemy are limited, help is desperatly needed.

Warm regards Paul

EDIT: I have added the relationships that exist on the "Book" table to "General" Table, but on the [pretty printed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HIY1lZKEw0) video he mentions that these are not important in the query!
Thanks @Sunny and @Rogan for looking

Just to clarify my question:
How do I construct the "case where", "aliasis 'CREDIT' 'DEBIT' 'ID' on 'A' 'B'" And then join the lot together, just a little break down of "how to"! :-)

Comment: Why don't you just create a `relationship` for each of `debit` and `credit` and `join` the tables on querying?

Comment: Hi @roganjosh I have a relationship created I have added it to my script but I am still at a loss on how to use that or write the query in flasksqlalchemy! sorry! Warm regards Paul